# Powershell error - Unexpected token error

Tags: powershell

I am getting an error while executing the below. Is the below method to concatenate $env:userprofile with path correct?

```
$env:userprofile\Documents\DNS\GetDnsRecord.ps1 | ConvertTo-Csv -NoTypeInformation | Select-Object -Skip 1 | Out-File -Append $env:userprofile\Documents\DNS\DnsRecord.csv
```

Error:

```
 + $env:userprofile\Documents\DNS\GetDnsRecord.ps1 | ConvertTo-Csv -NoTy ...
 +                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Unexpected token '\Documents\DNS\GetDnsRecord.ps1' in expression or statement.
```

Thanks for the help

John

Comment: Concatenating paths like that only works in argument-mode - prepend the entire thing with the call operator `&` and it'll work: `& $env:userprofile\Documents\DNS\GetDnsRecord.ps1 | ...`

Answer (score 1):

You might want to read a bit about Join-Path: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/join-path?view=powershell-7

```
Join-Path $env:userprofile '\Documents\DNS\GetDnsRecord.ps1'
```